# How to Collect couchbase logs into logstash?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, couchbase, logstash-grok

Can anyone help me with how to Collect couchbase logs into central logstash server ?

I tried to put all Couchbase logs in syslog and then my logstash-forwarder will forward syslog to central logstash server . 
So for this is tried this :

I checked my default.ini file

```
/opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.ini
```

which states :

```
[log]
file = /opt/couchbase/var/log/couchdb/couch.log
level = info
include_sasl = true
```

so i changed it to :

```
file = /var/log/syslog
```

but i find out, that logs were actually located here :

```
/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs
```

And the file in which the above path as been provide is :

```
/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config
```

Which looks like :

```
{error_logger_mf_dir, "/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs"}.
{path_config_bindir, "/opt/couchbase/bin"}.
{path_config_etcdir, "/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase"}.
{path_config_libdir, "/opt/couchbase/lib"}.
{path_config_datadir, "/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase"}.
{path_config_tmpdir, "/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/tmp"}.
```

But syslog does not have any Couchabse logs . (restarted the Couchbase as well to reload configurations)
Can anyone help me with this . Either i can put all logs in syslog or write a forwarder for Couchbase logs .

Comment: The path to the logs you have is correct. /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs Depending on what you are attempting to get out of the logs will tell you which files you need. Some of the log files are not as helpful in logstash as others because they are erlang logs and not exactly decipherable.